# Where is the C/C++ iTunes API? (not COM!)

Tags: c++, c, windows, sdk, itunes

I'm searching for the iTunes C/C++ API for creating plugins using dynamic libraries, but I just can't find it. I am not asking for the *COM Interface*.

Open-Source plugins like [VizKit](http://www.imagomat.de/vizkit/) and [iTunes Toaster](http://itunesnowplayin.sourceforge.net/) use it, and the source files I search for (*iTunesApi.h/.c*, *iTunesVisualAPI.h*) are included, but I'd rather get the source from an official repository instead of that kind of "workaround". Also, a documentation would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess both of those use the [Visualizer plugin SDK](http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunesvisualsdk.html).

Comment: Sometimes, I really doubt my google-skills. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=%2F%2Fdownloads%2Fdownload.action%3Fpath%3DApplications%2Fitunes_visual_plugins_sdk%2Fitunesvisualssdk.zip) link. Very useful stuff in there, too. I wonder why it isn't contained in the package *Jerry Coffin* posted.

Answer (score 0):

The *iTunes Visual Plug-ins SDK* can now be found in the [Downloads section](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?searchTextField=itunes%20visual%20plug-ins) of the *Apple Developers* website. However, you need to have an Apple Developer account to access this section (you can register one for free).